# How to execute BigQuery sql script using Apache Beam?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

BigQuery provides a way to use [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) that I want to utilize to create TEMP TABLES to limit calculating some intermediate CTs twice by the complex query.
Scripting prohibits use of destination_table in the configuration.
At the same time [beam.io.BigQuerySource](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.0.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySource) that I use, internally uses destination_table.
Is there any workaround to use BQ scripting in Apache Beam?

Comment: Have you looked at this ?https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.33.0/apache_beam.transforms.sql.html

Comment: @Mr.Batra this sql transform allows to use SQL to query data from pCollection I guess.